# Why is there a % after a number is printed on terminal in C++?

Tags: c++, integer

I am writing code and its output is a little different from the regular ones.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Value of x: " << x;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected only a integer but i got an output like this:[Output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69pNX.png)

Comment: looks like something from your terminal or IDE.  Try changing the line to `cout << "Value of x: " << x >> " ";` to see if it moves the `%` over a space

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that's you shell's prompt. You didn't print a new-line character ('\n').